# URL GET Request format using .htaccess with 2 or more params

Tags: php, .htaccess

well, i think this is a very common question but my question will focus on handling get request with more than two params with .htaccess format.

so for my current .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.php
```

it transformed

mydomain.com/basis_native/home.php

into.

mydomain.com/basis_native/home

but when I add a GET params it will be like this:

mydomain.com/basis_native/home?role=verifier&page=dashboard

what i want is to handle it to a nice way like:

mydomain.com/basis_native/home/verifier/dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `RewriteRule` to:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?role=$2&page=$3 [QSA]
```

Comment: They are probably relative URLs and are now trying to look for them in `/home/verifier/dashboard`, you can put a [`<base href="base-url">` in your page headers](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) to resolve the relative links, or you can change the relative links to absolute links.